# Proper way to change text and elements on a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text, coding-style

I've been using `innerHTML` and `innerText` for a while to change elements and text on web pages and I've just discovered that they are not W3C standard.

I've now found that `innerHTML` can be replaced with `createElement`, `setAttribute` and a few others but what is the best method for changing text inside an element?

I found a `textContent` as well but is there a standard way and is it widly implemented across older browsers?

Comment: http://www.developer-x.com/content/innerhtml

Comment: There is no JavaScript compliant consortium.  Browsers handle JavaScript differently - it's also the reason why JavaScript has a lot more wrong with it than it should.  When you do your W3C HTML/CSS validation, JavaScript isn't included for a reason.

Comment: @vol7ron: there's no "consortium", but ECMAScript is a widely accepted standard.  JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript.  However, the way we interact with web pages and the browser via JavaScript is the Document Object Model, which *is* standardized by W3C - http://www.w3.org/DOM/.

Comment: **@Andy E:** JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript, with extra stuff too - same with JScript or ActionScript.  It's like a database that is SQL compliant, but also has it's own additional functions.  -- The DOM is completely separate from JavaScript.  JavaScript is used to interact with the DOM; there's no standard to do that.  I didn't think it needed to be said, but the DOM is a model, not a script or language, it's the internal composition of the page.  -- The main reason to use setAttribute over innerHTML is due to the way different browsers do it - there's no standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*textContent* isn't implemented in IE8 and lower.  You can use [*createTextNode()*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536400(VS.85).aspx) similar to how you would use *createElement()*.  However, I often use discovery techniques to find out which property I need to use and keep a reference to it:

```
// You can use a shorter variable name if you want
var innerTextOrTextContent = "textContent" in document.body 
                               ? "textContent" : "innerText";

// Set an element's text:
myElement[innerTextOrTextContent] = "Added using: "+innerTextOrTextContent;
```

The *createTextNode()* example:

```
var tNode = document.createTextNode("Added using createTextNode()");
myElement.appendChild(tNode);
```

Something I often forget about, you can also directly set a text node's value, if you can get a reference to it:

```
// childNodes[0] is a text node:
myElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Added using nodeValue";
```

Example -  **http://jsfiddle.net/BxPaG/**.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the `createTextNode` method.

Would you say it would be silly to create a new `<span>` element with `createElement` and apply attributes and content and replace the old `<span>` element with 'replaceChild' instead of simply using `innerText` or 'textContent'?

Comment: @Ryan: yes, that wouldn't make much sense given that there are other options available.  You can use *replaceChild()* instead of *appendChild()* to replace the current text node.  Also, if you can get a reference to a text node, you can change it's value directly using *nodeValue* - see my update.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't go wrong by using whatever your javascript library offers for changing text (innerHtml for jQuery). After all one of the the main reasons for using such a library is having a platform that abstracts from different browser implementations.

Comment: What if he's not using a library?  Also, jQuery doesn't offer "innerHtml" for changing text.  The *text()* method should be used for that, *html()* is for setting HTML.

Comment: @Andy E: You are right, he might not use any. On the other hand, using javascript without any library is really painful for medium to large projects, at least if you want your website to work with all major browsers. I wouldn't want to do it.

Comment: and neither would I - I have in the past but it only makes sense to use a library now :-) For small, simple pages and scripts, I stick to vanilla JS though.